# Firestore function runs but does not always update

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am using React-Native with Firestore. I run a function to update the firestore database but it does not always update. Some times I have to press my button twice.

```
const markAsCompleted = async (id, isCompleted) => {
  console.log(id);
  await todoRef
    .doc(id)
    .update({
      isComplete: isCompleted,
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("mark As Completed Updated!");
    });
};

render(){
    return(
      <View>
          <Button onPress={()=> this.markAsCompleted('123', true)}
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your React Component Button is missing a closing tag and the function call  markAsCompleted is not appropriate as it has some es6 syntax errors.

I have made some changes to your code, see if this works.

```
import React,{Component} from “react”;
import {Button} from “ native-base”;
import {View} from “react-native”;
import firestore from “@react-native-firebase/firestore”;

export default class App extends Component{

async markAsCompleted =  (id, isCompleted) => { 
console.log(id); 
await firestore.collection(“collectionName”)
.doc(id)
 .update({ isComplete: isCompleted, })
 .then(() => { 
console.log("mark As Completed Updated!"); 
});
 }; 
render(){ 
return( 
<View>
 <Button onPress={()=> {this.markAsCompleted('123', true)} }>
</Button>
</View>
 ) }
}
```

- Also Make sure you have set your Firestore rules to accept update  transactions.
- Use this public documentation to get:
  [Real time updates in Firestore collections.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#node.js)
- You can listen to a document with the onSnapshot() method. An initial call using the callback you provide creates a document snapshot immediately with the current contents of the single document. Then,each time the contents change,another call updates the document snapshot.
- Also adding callback listeners to the function call can help you as you get success or error response.